# Handle Push Notification Navigation with Activity and Fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, push-notification, fragment

I develop one application with Firebase Push Notification feature.
I created one MainActivity and five fragment A, B, C, D, E.
I want to show Fragment C, when i clicked on Push Notification message, Its works fine when my application is open on screen.

But when I kill app and then push notification comes, I clicked on Push Notification, MainActivity load Fragment A which my initial Fragment with MainActivity.

My App Flow:

```
Splash Screen -> Login Screen (Silent Login) -> Main Activity -> Load a Specific Fragment
```

My code:

```
private void sendNotification(String title, String messageBody, int senderId) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(ARG_NOTIFICATION_FOR, ConstantValues.NOTIFICATION_FOR_CHAT_SCREEN);
        intent.putExtra(ARG_SENDER_ID, senderId);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0 /* Request code */, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

For MainActivity as below:

```
if(getIntent() != null)
{
  if (getIntent().hasExtra(ARG_NOTIFICATION_FOR))
  {
    //Load Fragment C
  }
}
```

When i clicked on Push Notification icon, App opens from Splash Screen with Silent Login -> Main Activity -> Load Fragment A

Main Activity not have hasExtra(ARG_NOTIFICATION_FOR)

Comment: get `intent` in `oncreate` of `MainActivity` and check if it's null or not, if it is not null then set `viewPager.setCurrentItem(C);`

Answer (score 6):

Your pending intent for push notification needs to send a parameter to activity to determine application is opened from icon or notification.

```
 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("FromNotification", true);//or fragment Id
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),notificationIndex,notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), notificationTitle, notificationMessage, pendingNotificationIntent);
```

You should create your custom notification for this purpose. Checkout this link https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html 

Also inside the onCreate method you should receive data from notification.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
       super.onCreate(bundle);
       //bla bla bla
       boolean fromNotification = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("FromNotification",false);
       if(fromNotification){
            //open fragment c
       }else{
            //open fragment a
       }
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant

Answer (score 1):

Add a `data` json to `payload` of your notification. Inside the `data` , you can pass additional information.

This information can be retrieved using `getIntent().getExtras()` inside the activity that launches. Following this, you can decide which fragment to display according to the information contained in the notification.

An example of a `payload` with `data` is as follows :-

```
payload = {
  notification: {
    title: `You have a new like on your post!`,
    click_action : 'HANDLE_NOTIFICATION'

  },
  data : {
        liker_uid : xyz,
        post_id : postId,
    }}
```